# JavaScript/Ajax - go to URL with form contents

Tags: javascript, ajax, url

I am trying to get a user to insert a customer_id and then have the URL to go to that page.

On: http://localhost:8080/viewCustomer.html, I want the user to input the customer_id and then I want the URL to go to http://localhost:8080/customers/{customer_id} .

I have tried looking at solutions on here and they are not working.

The result URL I get is "http://localhost:8080/viewCustomer.html?customer_id=1"

Here is my code:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script>
//            $("#submit").submit(function (event) {
//                $customer_id = $_POST["customer_id"];
//                var newURL = 'http://localhost:8080/customers/' + $customer_id;
//                xhttp.open("GET", newURL, true);
//                xhttp.send();
//            }
//            );

        function changeFormAction() {
            window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/" + document.getElementById("customer_id");  
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Bank Management - View Customer</h1>
    <h3>Please complete of the following:</h3>
    <form onsubmit="changeFormAction()">

        Customer ID:<br>
        <input type="text" name="customer_id" id="customer_id">
        <br>
        <button type="submit" onclick="">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What kind of project is this? Asp.net or not?

Comment: @JamesS In NetBeans. It's a Maven web application.

Answer (score 0):

You have included two ancient versions of jQuery. You should only include jQuery once, and ideally use an up-to-date version.

Once you have done that then your code should work as follows - you need to give your form an ID, handle "submit" on the *form* (buttons don't have a submit event), stop the default postback behaviour, and use jQuery's $.ajax() to easily send the ajax request.

```
<head>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
     <script>
       $(function() {
         $("#customerForm").submit(function(event) {
             event.preventDefault();
             $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "http://localhost:8080/customers/" + $("#customer_id").val(),
             }).done(function(response) {
               console.log(response);
             }).fail(jqXHR, textStatus) {
               alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
             });
         });
      });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Bank Management - View Customer</h1>
    <h3>Please complete the following:</h3>
    <form id="customerForm">
        Customer ID:<br>
        <input type="text" name="customer_id" id="customer_id">
        <br>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Here are some related documentation links:

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

https://api.jquery.com/submit/

https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. :( The URL just changes to `http://localhost:8080/viewCustomer.html?customer_id=1`.

I don't know if it's because its a NetBeans/Maven web application.

Comment: Sorry I think I forgot a crucial part of the JavaScript - a "document ready" wrapper around the "submit" handler, so that the code to create the event handler doesn't run until the page is loaded. Otherwise it will run the moment the script tag is added to the page (which is of course before the form, because things are added in the order they appear in the HTML document), and at that time the form doesn't exist, so there's nothing to bind the event to. See the edit which should resolve the issue.